# Can other players see me on their map?

Tags: pokemon-go

Are other players able to see you on their map in Pokemon Go? I am concerned that if I use the game, stalkers and other such people would be able to find me. I have searched for an answer for this question on other forums, but have yet to find the answer.

Comment: If any of the answers here satisfy you, please "Accept" their answer as a thank-you for their time! :-)

Answer (score 29):

No there is no way to see other players except seeing them in person staring at their phones while next to a random fountain.

Comment: It's pretty recognizable, though

Comment: Could as well be an Ingress player :)

Comment: Nah. Ingress players don't walk and stare nearly as much since our targets (Portals) are in set, known locations (unlike the random pokemon and grass tufts that Go players have to chase).
Not saying it CAN'T be an Ingress player, just that it's less likely.

Answer (score 15):

As of now, there is no way for other Trainers to see you on the map, except for Gyms.

A Trainer looking at a gym can see that you've been there before, or if he sees the gym flip to you, he knows you're there now.

Additionally, players may see who deployed a Lure Patch on a Pokestop. As these only last 30 minutes, it could theoretically be used to trace players. (Thanks, [@StephenSchrauger](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/17595/stephen-schrauger))

Of course, people can always see your screen and know that you play, and potentially who you are in-game.

Other than that, there is no way to locate other Trainers (yet).

Comment: Note also that you can see the username of a trainer who placed a Lure Module on a PokeStop. Since those only last 30 minutes, and since it draws pokemon, it's a high indicator that the trainer is currently in the area.

Answer (score -3):

I think there is a way to see other trainers...I was at a park and my phone was in my bag when I walked past some guys...afterwards one yelled.."she's a trainer! That girl was a Pokemon trainer!" So he must have had some means of detecting that with his app.

Comment: Or there was another person playing, and they assumed. Or they thought you looked like a character out of Pokemon..

Comment: Or that guy saw you playing some other time and recognized you. That would explain why he used the past tense "was" instead of "is"--he may have been referring to an earlier time when he saw you.